# Cordova intercept XMLHttpRequest / Websocket

Tags: cordova, webview, xmlhttprequest, intercept

we develop a ionic app which is using cordova. We need to intercept all XMLHttpRequest and Websocket calls to change some headers. Android System WebView does adding Origin header file:// to request which is not an allowed schema for 3rd part rest service.

So I'm searching the possibilty to intercept this calls from android and also from ios if possible and add or remove some headers?

Could something like this possible?

Comment: Hi Michael. We are facing same Origin header issue for XMLHttpRequests for Cordova app. Could you please help us if there is any workaround/solution you did for this?